# C# cant see mysql database

Tags: c#, mysql

I've recently installed a MySQL database on one of my servers using PHPMyAdmin, but when it comes to connecting to it in C#, the database isn't found! the PHPMyAdmin is available at http://domain.co.uk/phpmyadmin and i can browse and edit it fine, but when it comes to using the database manager in C# it says that it cannot connect to the server, any help is appreciated!

Comment: are you using a db user that is allowed to connect from any host? MySQL doesn't just separate users by their name but also by the host name they connect from. For instance, the root user created after installing mysql is only allowed to connect from localhost. If your user has a similar restriction you'd have to create a user without that restriction.

Comment: What is the script you're trying to connect to the db with? Are the db connection information and credentials correct?

Comment: Credentials are certainly correct, and im using the root to connect. I had a localhost phpmyadmin which worked perfectly with root

Comment: Im using the mysql database connector that they give out

Comment: The C# application, is it on a remote system or localhost?

Comment: C# is on my PC, the database is on a remote system

Comment: Oh, clarification, the old database i could connect to was localhost, along with the program, but i cant leave my PC on 24/7 :)

Comment: Does the firewall on the remote system (if any) permit connections?

Comment: No firewall as far as i know, i can always contact the server hosts and see if there is, although im fairly sure that theres no firewall

Comment: Did you try telnet to connect to the DB? Just to make sure it's up and running and accepting incoming connections.

Comment: can you show the connection string that you are currently using to connect to the remote database.. sounds like an issue with the connection string defined in your .config file and or hard coded in your .cs file which hardcoding is a `POOR` option

Comment: Im not using a connectionstring, im using the database sources

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what you've written in the comments, it certainly sounds like your MySQL server is not allowing connections from other machines (or, at the very least, not for the root user).

Most hosts do not allow MySQL connections from arbitrary machines (with good reason!) by blocking the MySQL port on their router/firewall. This is usually a Good Thing but can cause annoyances when, say, you're developing an application at home and want to use your hosted database. Most MySQL installations do not accept connections from other machines, either (out of the box, my MySQL server accepted the user root connecting from the local host name, '127.0.0.1', or 'localhost'). Either of these scenarios will keep you from being able to connect from home. phpMyAdmin works because it's on your host's webserver and to MySQL it is coming from either localhost, 127.0.0.1, or some other trusted host as configured by your hosting provider.

@SaniHuttunen has good advice; if you can telnet to your host on port 3306 (or whatever port MySQL is using if not the standard one) then it's the second of the limitations and easily resolved by creating a new user with a proper (or, ugh, wildcard) host. If your hosting provider is blocking your connection, you'll have to take it up with them.

When connecting to MySQL, the host 'localhost' refers to socket connections, '127.0.0.1' is a local connection via TCP/IP networking, '%' is a wildcard to mean *any* host (except not socket connections), and of course you can use a specific host name or IP address as well.

Please carefully consider security and take appropriate precautions before opening up your server to accept connections from the internet.